# Iron golems spawning underwater?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have built an iron farm in Bedrock Edition 1.19.10. There was a cave under the farm which was filled with water. I didn't worry about it because I read in the Minecraft Wiki that there must not be 2 blocks of water above the spawning block in order for an iron golem to spawn. After I finished my iron farm it worked well and spawned 9 golems and then it stopped working. I found that 2 golems have spawned in the cave. So, can iron golems spawn underwater in Bedrock Edition  1.19? How can I fix this? Is this a glitch or a bug?